# How do I convert strings to enumerations?

Tags: matlab, enums

To convert an enumeration to be a character array is straightforward – you just call `char`.

```
char(myenum.somevalue)
```

returns `'somevalue'`.

How do convert back again?  I was expecting something like `char2enum` where

```
char2enum('somevalue', 'myenum')
```

returns `myenum.somevalue`.

Is there a builtin function for this or must I create my own?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating an enum from a character is also fairly straightforward: Just create the enumeration:

`out = myenum.somevalue`

returns out with class `myenum` and value `somevalue`.

If your string is in a variable, call

```
someVariable = somevalue;
out = myenum.(someVariable)
```

Comment: This is bothersome, because it means implementing similar logic in each enumeration.  In my proposed function, you pass the name of an enumeration in, so it knows what the available values are.

Comment: Such a function shouldn't be much hassle to write but I figured that it ought to exist already.

Comment: @Richie Cotton: Oh, I see. Actually all you need to do is create a static method for a superclass of all your enums. This would call the class' constructor and set the value of the enum, so it should really not be much of a hassle.

Comment: @Richie Cotton: Looking over the documentation makes me believe that it's actually really, really simple (see my edit).

Comment: Excellent. It doesn't get easier than that.  In fact even `myenum.('somevalue')` works.

Answer (score 6):

You can use MATLAB Dynamic reference feature to access the enumeration by its name as a string instead of its symbolic name.  For example, given a class `Weekdays`

```
classdef Weekdays
   enumeration
    Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday
   end
end
```

You can access the `Friday` type in a couple of ways:

```
>> Weekdays.Friday  % Access symbolically

>> Weekdays.('Friday') % Access as a string
```

If you have a string variable with the name of the class that works too:

```
>> day = 'Friday'
>> Weekdays.(day)
```

BTW, this feature works for MATLAB Class methods, properties, and events, as well as struct fields.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/bsgigzp-1.html#bsgigzp-33

Answer (score 2):

I know this question has been answered a long time ago, but I just found out about a different solution which can be pretty neat when using enums in an argument block. Also I couldn't find any reference to this feature in the official documentation so I thought I'd post it here:

The constructor for any enumeration can be called using an element name as sole argument. E.g.

```
>> Weekdays('Friday')
  
ans = 

  Weekdays enumeration

    Friday
```

Ok, so we can omit the dot. But why is this interesting? Well, when using enums as a function argument, the argument block allows for automatic conversion from string/char to enumeration.

```
function test(day)
    arguments
        day Weekdays
    end
    day
end
```

.

```
>> test('Friday')

day = 

  Weekdays enumeration

    Friday
```